# best way to log large amounts of data

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation, log

I'm building a new logging system for our company. I'm wondering about the best way to store about 50-100GB data each year.

I'm looking at both MySQL and MongoDB. I'm considering MongoDB because it looks easy to expand to lots of data and it works pretty fast. I'm considering MySQL because I've used it before.

We have a log database today in MySQL which uses InnoDB and foreign keys. It has over 200GB data. It's not working well and the database crashes whenever I try to remove anything from it. I'm not the one who built it, I'm just trying to fix the problem.

I hope people out there know a good way to log this amount of data. I just need a reliable way to store and a simple way to query. I'm open to other options.

The logs are generated on separate servers, gathered to a central log server and imported. I'm building an API to access them when we need to query them.

Comment: The ELK stack would be a good choice. It includes components that aid in your objective including a log forwarder, a log parser, Elastic for the data storage, and a visualization package named Kibana. See elastic.co for more information regarding the ELK stack.

Comment: 100GB per year is not huge :-) Any *distributed* system should be able to handle this easily in a structure partitioned by day (and scales, too). If it will be NoSQL/Hadoop/DBMS mainly depends on what your going to do with those logs (complexity) and they kind of information you're trying to extract. Is this going to be related to other data within the company?

Comment: The data in this system is comming from a webshop, we automatic update and insert our products for companys like 300.000 products each day changes, i need to lot whats happen about the price going down, up or equel the same as the stock the the primary log we do, and right now our database are pretty stuck and its not running as smooth we think its shut :)

So what i understand on you @dnoeth its we can use MongoDB its will be a fine choose?

Comment: NoSQL/Hadoop is great for processing large amount of data like yours and/or a kind of sequential processing (e.g. time series). It only sucks when it's getting more complicated (e.g. joining multiple sources). And of course DBMSes do data processing a few years longer, so their query optimization capabilities are still superior.

Comment: Thats sound pretty nice, we don't use joins in our log tables, its only to lots of insert and load the abount out from a key there bind out, agin! :) thanks a lot can i accept you ass a awser, :)

Comment: Go for Elasticsearch - If  you need to load the data from text files add logstash and logstash forwarder to the mix

Comment: i not understand what you mean @Spörri :/ can you explain it? :)

Comment: With just 100GB of data a year, you can use whatever the hell you want. That is such a small amount of data in the grand scheme of things, that your issue is not likely to be constrained to the platform you choose. It sounds like your issue is more infrastructure/design issues than the capability of the software you're using.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson when will you say i need to change platform how much data are we spekaing about? 1TB, 10TB, 100TB or more?

Comment: I'm saying your choice of platform should not really be relative to 100GB of data as all platforms should comfortably be able to handle that amount of data. It just depends on how you structure and index it and your choice of server. What is the structure of the log table? Can you show some queries? What are you currently hosting on that is causing issues?

Comment: Right now i need to rebuild it, i'm building a new platform, so i need to know what i need to choose before starting, i have thinking on MySQL using MyISAM widt DelayIndex, that what i thinking, but i'm not sure its a good way.

Comment: What is the specification of the server?

Comment: Right now, i don't know but i think we get access to 64gb memeory+ and 1-2x hex-core xeon cpu's but i'm not realy sure.

Answer (score 1):

ELK Stack is a good choice, even though i use elastic search + gray log for logging purposes. Experience with elastic search, several hundreds of GB are not an issue, u can in any case, easily increase capacity adding new nodes to it.

Graylag has an API which you could use in any other app